# Rails4.2 : Images not showing up using Aws S3/Paperclip Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Have an app using Rails / AWS S3 storage & paperclip Gem. Allows users to upload logos , works fine but does not display mages correctly. I get the name of the image. I have added an image_url which displays the correct url uploaded from amazon s3. and it appears in the ruby console as well.

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > Job.last.image.url
  Job Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs"  ORDER BY "jobs"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => "http://s3.amazonaws.com/jXXXXX/jobs/images/000/000/011/original/g
```

Amazon s3 bucket permissions have been set to everyone can view. have added image to my params method

settings in application.rb file

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Job1
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de


    # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
    config.paperclip_defaults = { 
        storage: :s3,
        s3_region: 'us-west-2',
        s3_credentials:{
            bucket: ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
            access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
            secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
        }
    }
  end
end
```

_job.html.erb

```
<ul id="timeline">
  <a href="#">
    <li class="listing clearfix">
        <div class="image_wrapper">
           <%= link_to job_path(job) do %>
           <%= image_tag job.image.url(:original), class: "img-responsive" %>
          <% end %>
          <%= job.image.url(:original) %>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <span class="job_title"><%= link_to job.title, job_path(job) %></span>
            <span class="job_info"><%= job.company %><span>&bull;</span> New York <span>
            &bull;</span>Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(job.created_at) %> ago</span>
        </div>
            <span class="job_type full_time"> Full-Time</span>
        </li>

      </a>

    </ul>

.env file

AWS_BUCKET=joXXXXX
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AXXXXXXXXXXXXXXTFFQ
AWS_S3_REGION=us-west-2
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=yXXXXXXXXXF+gjekFrVz1rG
```

added the url in the browser and got this

`PermanentRedirect`The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.jXXXXXXjXXXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com79XXXXXXZiMAI/J3XXXXXXI2VylhR7Ch3+/Pi+J68gcQ=

but have updated permission on amazon s3

Comment: after running `Job.last.image.url` it gives you url can you copy and past to browser url and check it yourself, to make sure it loads in the browser.

Comment: yes got an error message regarding endpoints

Comment: did u check your AWS bucket? did it upload ? check bucket permissions too.

Comment: bucket permissions checked and it shows up in the browser https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/joXXXXX1/jobs/

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint error message says:

PermanentRedirectThe bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.jXXXXXX**jXXXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com**79XXXXXXZiMAI/J3XXXXXXI2VylhR7Ch3+/Pi+J68gcQ=

Your url is:

s3.amazonaws.com/jXXXXX/jobs/images/

But it's expected to be:

jXXXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com

You must add the endpoint on your paperclip defaults using the s3_host_name var.

```
config.paperclip_defaults = { 
   s3_host_name: "s3-#{ENV['AWS_REGION']}.amazonaws.com", }
```

More about this: [aws documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html)